# delete using checkbox code not working properly

Tags: php, html

Code not working properly always shows the message fail.

```
function delete(){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rishita_db");
    $sql="select * from 14_patientdetails";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
    <center>
    <h1><u>Patient Details</u></h1>
    <table border="1" style="font-family:Georgia;color:#800000;font-style:bold;">
    <tr style="font-family:Georgia;color:green;font-style:bold;">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Patient ID</th>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone No.</th>
        <th>Medicare</th>
        <th>Doctor Associated</th>
     </tr>
     <form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $r=$row['patientId'];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id="checkbox" value=<?php echo $r; ?>></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['patientId']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['patientName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['DOB']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Medicare']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Doctor']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>


    <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="del" type="submit" id="del" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>      
    </table>
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["del"]))
    {
        if(isset($_POST["checkbox"]))
        echo 'Enter';

        $chk = isset($_POST['checkbox']);
        $chkcount = count($chk);
        for($i=0;$i<$chkcount;$i++){
            $del=$chk[$i];
            $sql1 = "DELETE FROM 14_patientdetails WHERE id='$del'";
            $q = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
        }


        if($q){
            echo "Success";
        }else{
            echo 'Fail';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add the HTML part to your question.

Comment: Have you tried to echo $del; and see if you're getting the desired values?

Comment: `$chk = isset($_POST['checkbox']);`. And then, `$del=$chk[$i];`.  This is wrong. $chk is not an array.

Comment: I tried to do echo $del.Noting is printed.what is the solution?

Comment: That's because you're messing up with the $chk, as @codeSun mentioned. Do not assign $chk to isset(); plus. I see two <form> tags and a single closing </form> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$chk = isset($_POST['checkbox']);
$chkcount = count($chk);
for($i=0;$i<$chkcount;$i++){
    $del=$chk[$i];
```

Now there are one too many mistakes, multiple `<form>` tags and a single closing `</form>`

I couldn't not edit your code on my phone so I will suggest the way to get along. I'm pretty sure you'll love it when you do it yourself.

Make `a <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox" value = "<?php echo $r; ?>"/>Proceed</td>` inside a `while-loop` something similar to your code `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

In the end of the `<form>` make a `<button>` and redirect user to another page probably `delete.php`. Now, check its set;

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']
{ 
//foreach loop for your query
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val)
{
// check what you're getting..
echo $val;
}}
```

You could also use a simple `for-loop`
If you want:

```
for($i = 0; $i <count($_POST['checkbox']; $i++)
{
// do your stuff..
}
```

Bottom line: try  to differentiate your forms, queries and make a single loop to read from database and assign the values at the same time to your checkboxes.

> This is what I have understood and tried to write from my phone,
>   please study mysqli/PDO to prevent SQL Injection/XSS.

Comment: @riya This was not suppose to be copy/pasted as it is. What erros are you getting?